# outlook 2003 Crashes before it launches

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2003

everytime i go to open my outlook 2003 it crashes before it opens. i have done a fresh reinstall and keep getting the crash.

> AppName: outlook.exe   AppVer: 12.0.6607.1000  ModName: kernel32.dll
>   ModVer: 5.1.2600.5781    Offset: 00012afb

[image]

Any help resolving this would be much appricated

Comment: Have you tried starting outlook in safe mode? outlook.exe /safe

Comment: Sorry that code doesnt seem to work

Comment: I'm with Melvin. What happens when you type `outlook.exe /safe` in the Start > Run window? How does that not seem to work, exactly? (there is a space between `outlook` and `/safe`.)

Comment: I have worked out answer it in the shortvut it seemed to embaded the root for office 2007 insead of 2003 so i cahnged that and it worked fine